# How to make a port forward in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, port-forwarding

I'd like to make all incoming connections to port 1000 of my host (IP: 200.234.XXX.XXX) to be forward to the port 80 on host 10.211.55.5

How can I do it on my host? It is running Mac OS X 10.5.8

Comment: ah, you're also running parallels, having the same problem as I? :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Quite simple to do,
Firstly you will need to enable the remote login service on your mac (*System Preferences* -> *Sharing* -> *Remote Login*). This starts your ssh server.

Then run the following command in your OS X Terminal:

```
ssh -L 200.234.XXX.XXX:10000:10.211.55.5:80 -N 127.0.0.1
```

You may need to accept the server fingerprint initially as well as type in your local password for ssh login. (You can also set up a local to local ssh public / private key to make it not prompt for a password, will leave that as an exercise for the reader.)

The format is:

```
ssh -L local_addr:local_port:remote_addr:remote_port -N 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can we do it if port 22 is not open?

Comment: You need to connect somehow. But you can always run ssh on another port... perhaps http port? or the BIND (DNS) port? Those are mostly open on firewalls.

Comment: I get connection refused, even though I can connect to the remote server from the browser.

Comment: Just enable Remote Access in MacOS Sharing Settings. You need an enabled ssh server for this to work :)

Answer (score 26):

Very simple using the versatile tool ncat:

```
sudo ncat --sh-exec "ncat 10.211.55.5 80" -l 1000 --keep-open
```

Get the binaries of ncat/nmap for Mac OS X from the official website:
http://nmap.org/download.html#macosx

EDIT: added sudo to listen on a restricted port <1024

Comment: thanks. it is very simple besides it doesn't need to reboot!

Comment: Also you don't need to start the SSH server on your macOS.

Comment: You can also install the `ncat/nmap` via homebrew: `brew install nmap`.

Comment: Work for local connections, is there any way to make it accept requests from other clients in the same network?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a UPnP router, its easy to configure ports by using [PortMap](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/portmap/)

It has a very simple UI.

[image]

Comment: why is your image so tiny?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can tell you how I do that sort of thing on my Mac OS X 10.5.8 system.

I started on an answer about NAT, but I think you actually want a TCP forwarder program instead (you mention 'proxy' and port forwarding.)

There's a few ways of doing this, depending upon your needs even 'SSH' can be pressed into action, though my favourite short and sweet way is a Perl script [tcpforward](http://search.cpan.org/~acg/tcpforward-0.01/tcpforward).

If you need some HTTP manipulation (you might need to tweak HTTP redirects, so that when a request comes for a URL without a trailing '/' you don't get redirected to the real, inaccessible, server), then Apache can do the job of a reverse proxy. You'll want to look at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_proxy.html) and specifically ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. Do **not** enable ProxyRequests, that's for forward proxying. It should be possible to use Mac OS's own Apache to do this, if you've got it running. It does come with mod_proxy and /etc/httpd/httpd.conf is the config file to update.

Even with Apache, you need to make sure that all the links in the real server's content are relative, if they reference the real server then you could try the mod_proxy_html module (I have no experience of how well that works.)

Comment: +1 for tcpforward, Perl never stops being useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still interested, I've developed an App for port forwarding on macOS. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/hronro/iPortForwarder

It allows you to easily forward a single port or a range of ports without modifying the system firewall.

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1198518)

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine connected directly to the internet (IE - without a router)? Normally you do the port forwarding on the router, but if you do use a modem to connect directly, iptables is probably the best way.

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted down because it's the truth.

Comment: @HasaanChop This is downvoted because it isn't helpful. If it detailed exactly how to use `iptables` to accomplish what the question asked, that could be useful.

Comment: There is no iptables on mac os x.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article: http://www.cyberhq.nl/article/384/port-forwarding-in-macos-x

But since you are forwarding to 80 I'm assuming you want it to go to a web server so I would just change the web server config to set up a reverse proxy or something like that.

Comment: Looks like the link is broken