# Accessing localhost web server via reverse SSH tunnel and URL

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

I have a web server running on a local machine and it is easily accessible to all machines on the LAN. I also have a remote server with a public IP address/URL pointing to it (example.com). I cannot access my local server from outside of my network because I'm stuck behind my ISP's NAT (they won't grant public IP or port forward anything), so I'm trying to configure a reverse SSH tunnel to grant public access.

I am running `ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 jemeadows@example.com -i $SSH_KEY -N` on the local server to try to create the tunnel.

Using eLinks on the remote server, I can access 127.0.0.1:8080, and it correctly displays the sites on the local server. However, visiting example.com:8080 in the browser does not show anything. I've tried using local port forwarding to redirect incoming traffic to 127.0.0.1:8080 but that doesn't work. Any other ideas to redirect incoming traffic from a web browser into my SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-R 8080:localhost:80` is usually not enough. See [`man 1 ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#R) [emphasis mine]:

> `-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`
> […]
>
> Specifies that connections to the given TCP port or Unix socket on the remote (server) host are to be forwarded to the local side.
>
> […]
>
> **By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only.** This may be overridden by specifying a `bind_address`. An empty `bind_address`, or the address `*`, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a remote `bind_address` will only succeed if the server's `GatewayPorts` option is enabled (see `sshd_config(5)`).

Your tries with `127.0.0.1:8080` on the server indicate the listening socket is bound to the loopback interface. Most likely it is not bound to any other interface.

You need to explicitly specify `bind_address` or to use `*` or to use an empty string as `bind_address`. The option with an empty `bind_address` looks like this (note the leading `:`):

```
-R :8080:localhost:80
```

Additionally the state of `GatewayPorts` in the `sshd_config` on the server is important. From [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#GatewayPorts):

> `GatewayPorts`
>
> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to ports forwarded for the client. By default, `sshd(8)` binds remote port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. `GatewayPorts` can be used to specify that `sshd` should allow remote port forwardings to bind to non-loopback addresses, thus allowing other hosts to connect. The argument may be `no` to force remote port forwardings to be available to the local host only, `yes` to force remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address, or `clientspecified` to allow the client to select the address to which the forwarding is bound. The default is `no`.

To achieve what you want the option must not be `no`. Note `no` is the default value, so unspecified `GatewayPorts` still means `no`. The value of `yes` will make `-R 8080:localhost:80` work like `-R :8080:localhost:80`.

I advise `GatewayPorts clientspecified` in the server config and `ssh -R :8080:localhost:80 …` on the client.

After changing the config file you need to restart the SSH server or otherwise tell it to reload the configuration. `sshd` from OpenSSH rereads its configuration upon receiving a hangup signal, SIGHUP.

---

Possible additional problems:

- The firewall on the server may block connections to the `8080` port coming in from the Internet.
- The local HTTP server may reject requests that use `example.com` (compare [Why does the original site work, but port forwarding to the same site fails?](https://superuser.com/q/1541704/432690)).

Comment: Ok, that actually makes sense, preventing outside connections by default. By setting GatewayPorts and passing an empty bind-address, the local address of  `netstat -an` changed from `127.0.0.1:8080` to `0.0.0.0:8080`, so it looks like that should accept traffic from any source, right? It still fails to connect from my web browser, but if I try to connect and check netstat again, I see a bunch of entries that show the IP I'm connecting from, but with a `TIME_WAIT` status instead of `LISTEN` or `ESTABLISHED`.

Comment: So it didn't work yesterday, but when I opened it up to play around some more, it ended up working today! Thanks again for those tips, I guess something must've restarted or updated overnight and fixed whatever was the problem.