# ssh: Unsupported Match attribute final: Bad match condition

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

In my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```bash
Match originalhost my_server final exec "my_executable vault ssh cert"
Host my_server
  HostName something.my_server.com
  User first.last
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  ForwardAgent yes
  ForwardX11 yes
```

Whenever I run `ssh my_server`, I get these errors:

```
$ ssh my_server
Unsupported Match attribute final
/home/gabriel/.ssh/config line 1: Bad Match condition
```

What's the problem? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. `ssh -V` shows:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that this version of openssh (7.6p1) is just too old, and doesn't support "Match attribute `final`".

So, the solution is to just upgrade your version of openssh! I upgraded to 8.9p1 and it works fine now.

Go here and download the latest .tar.gz file you want: https://mirrors.sonic.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/

I chose `openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz` since that version of openssh was working fine with this `~/.ssh/config` file on another computer.

Extract the .tar.gz file. (Note: this took a long time for me!-- greater than 5 minutes)

Then, build and install it:

```bash
cd openssh-8.9p1  # change the folder name for your case
./configure
make
sudo make install

# refresh your shell by re-sourcing
. ~/.profile
```

Now `ssh -V` shows this:

```bash
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

...and `ssh my_server` works fine!

Fixed.