# Using socat to bypass NAT

Tags: networking, nat, vnc, socat

I`m facing the following problem:

Lets call my machine the PC-1 and a remote machine which i want to access, the PC-2. PC-1 and PC-2 are in different networks, and both are behind a NAT.

To achieve connecting PC-1 to PC-2, i used a third machine with a valid external IP (A VPS) running socat.

So, PC-2 is running a VNC server on port 5900. To create the tunnel, i used socat with this syntax:

```
socat tcp-l:10000 tcp4:localhost:5900
```

And on the VPS:

```
socat tcp-l:20000 tcp-l:10000
```

So, if i connect PC-1 using the VPS IP Address and port 20000, the connection works, and i receive the VNC session from PC-2 My questions are:

1:Is there a more practical way to do this? Did i thought too far?

2:When the session finishes, i can't connect again until i restart socat in both machines. Is there a way to keep the sockets listening again? (I know about the fork and reuseaddr, but how to use them?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Such tunneling is usually done with `ssh -R` (can be automatized with `autossh`). Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1566894/432690).

Comment: socat for forwarding vnc through the internet is a bad idea because vnc is totally insecure. A secure tunnel via ssh port forwarding is the preferred solution (forwarding only while ssh is active).

Comment: Sure. I'll try using SSH instead. Thanks!