# Reverse autoSSH tunnel does not work

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

For some reason my autossh reverse tunnel does not work.

This is my command:

```
└─# autossh -M 12121 -N -f -o "PubkeyAuthentication=yes" -o "PasswordAuthentication=no" -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa -R 12345:localhost:22 root@amazon
```

But for some reason, a listener opens on port 12121 over SSH
and another one opens on 12122 for autossh.
However, none opens at 12345
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7rHq.png)

Comment: As per [autossh's manual](https://manpages.debian.org/autossh/autossh.1.en.html#Connection_setup): does it work when using only ssh without involving autossh? "It cannot be stressed enough that you must make sure ssh works on its own, that you can set up the session you want before you try to run it under autossh"

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). Not only you should post text as text; you should clearly state the exact command that gave you this output and where it was invoked (locally or `@amazon`).

Answer (score 0):

`autossh -M 12121 …` opens ports `12121` and `12122` on the local side (where `autossh` works). `-R 12345:localhost:22` is a request to open port `12345` on the *remote* side. I think `12121` is also used on the remote side, but the sole fact you observed `12122` used by `autossh` (which is a local process) tells me you were investigating things locally.

On the local computer you observed `12121` and `12122` being listened on. You did not observe `12345` being listened on because your local computer is *not* the remote server you had connected to.

If you `ssh` to the remote server and look there then you will probably find port `12345` open for listening (note: probably [on the loopback interface only](https://superuser.com/a/1566917/432690)).

If you want a tunnel that listens locally then you need `-L`, not `-R`. I guess in this particular case you really want a tunnel that listens remotely, i.e. `-R`. The problem was you looked for its listening end on the wrong machine.