# SSH remote connection not connecting

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I'm trying to remotely access an external device connected to my linux device ( behind a firewall ) from a windows machine. I have a public server and have `GatewayPorts` set to `yes` in the ssh configuration file.

I'm unable to get it to work.

I'm connecting to the server from my linux machine using :

```
sudo ssh -i .....pem -N user@host -R 0.0.0.0:5555:127.0.0.1:80
```

[image]

**Ultimately I need to access not `127.0.0.1` but another device connected on the ethernet port (it's pingable). Would that be possible? Suppose I want to connect that device's port `502` through the server ?**

And when I check the opened ports on the server using `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`, it shows the port open but only to `localhost`

[image]

I think that's why it's not accessible from my windows machine when I try to access it using `my-server-hostname:5555`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Also I noticed that after manually terminating the ssh session on linux machine after a while keeps the port `5555` open on the server. This shouldn't happen.

Comment: "and have `GatewayPorts` set to `yes` in the ssh configuration file" – Ssh? Do you mean `ssh_config` and/or `~/.ssh/config`? `GatewayPorts` in these affect `-L`. What matters for `-R` is `GatewayPorts` [*in `sshd_config` on the server*](https://superuser.com/a/1566917/432690). Please clarify what configuration file you mean.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think it was `ssh_config` file. Turned out I had modified the wrong file